# A multi-language IOS app

Tags: ios, swift

How to build a multi-language app? I already build one app but it’s English, I want to make it multi-language, and show the language depends on system language.
Appreciate if you give a help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it demonstrates a total lack of willingness even to _glance_ at the documentation.

Comment: A fast google search bring me this great tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually quite easy.  You basically have a text file for each language you are supporting.  Apple's documentation steps you through how to do it:

https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/